# Out range Error while trying to copy worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros

The whole macro should open a file from a site and then copy a specific worksheet and paste into another workbook. So far the macro opens but fails to copy and paste throwing an  "out of range error" error. I'm looking at either fixing that error or opening the workbook then deleting the extra sheets that I don't want to see. Any help will be appreciated!

```
Public Sub OpenFileFromWeb()
' Define Workbook and Worksheet Variables
Dim wkbMyWorkbook As Workbook
Dim wkbWebWorkbook As Workbook
Dim wksWebWorkSheet As Worksheet
Set wkbMyWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

' Open The Web Workbook
    Workbooks.Open ("http://path.path.com/path/site/path/test_Data.xls")
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select

' Set the Web Workbook and Worksheet Variables
Set wkbWebWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set wksWebWorkSheet = ActiveSheet

' Choose Sheet to pull Data from
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy

' Copy The Web Worksheet To My Workbook and Rename
    wksWebWorkSheet.Copy After:=wkbMyWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)'-->error occurs here
    wkbMyWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = "MyNewWebSheet"

' Close the Web Workbook
    wkbMyWorkbook.Activate
    wkbWebWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot

```
Public Sub OpenFileFromWeb()

    Dim wkbMyWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim wkbWebWorkbook As Workbook
    Set wkbMyWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

    Set wkbWebWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("http://path.path.com/path/site/path/test_Data.xls")

    With wkbMyWorkbook
        wkbWebWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Copy _
            After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        .Sheets(.Sheets.Count).Name = "MyNewWebSheet"
    End With

    ' Close the Web Workbook
    wkbMyWorkbook.Activate
    wkbWebWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to qualify which workbook you're using on `sheets.count`.

I've tidied up your code while I'm here:

```
Public Sub OpenFileFromWeb()

    ' Define Workbook and Worksheet Variables
    Dim wkbMyWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim wkbWebWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim wksWebWorkSheet As Worksheet
    Set wkbMyWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

    ' Open The Web Workbook and Set the Web Workbook and Worksheet Variables
    Set wkbWebWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("http://path.path.com/path/site/path/test_Data.xls")
    Set wksWebWorkSheet = wkbWebWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

    ' Choose Sheet to pull Data from
    wksWebWorkSheet.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy '''NOT SURE WHAT THIS IS FOR. DOESN'T SEEM TO BE REQUIRED!

    ' Copy The Web Worksheet To My Workbook and Rename
    wksWebWorkSheet.Copy after:=wkbMyWorkbook.Sheets(wkbMyWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    wkbMyWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = "MyNewWebSheet"

    ' Close the Web Workbook
    wkbMyWorkbook.Activate
    wkbWebWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```